# How to search a set of normally distributed parameters using optuna?

Tags: python, optimization, hyperparameters, hyperopt, optuna

I'm trying to optimize a custom model (no fancy ML whatsoever) that has 13 parameters, 12 of which I know to be normally distributed. I've gotten decent results using the `hyperopt` library:

```
space = {
    'B1': hp.normal('B1', B1['mean'], B1['std']),
    'B2': hp.normal('B2', B2['mean'], B2['std']),
    'C1': hp.normal('C1', C1['mean'], C1['std']),
    'C2': hp.normal('C2', C2['mean'], C2['std']),
    'D1': hp.normal('D1', D1['mean'], D1['std']),
    'D2': hp.normal('D2', D2['mean'], D2['std']),
    'E1': hp.normal('E1', E1['mean'], E1['std']),
    'E2': hp.normal('E2', E2['mean'], E2['std']),
    'F1': hp.normal('F1', F1['mean'], F1['std']),
    'F2': hp.normal('F2', F2['mean'], F2['std'])
}
```

where I can specify the shape of the search space per parameter to be normally distributed.

I've got 32 cores and the default `Trials()` object only uses one of them.  `Hyperopt` suggests two ways to parallelize the search process, both of which I could not get to work on my windows machine for the life of me, so I've given up and want to try a different framework.

Even though Bayesian Hyper Parameter Optimization as far as I know is based on the idea that values are distributed according to a distribution, and the normal distribution is so prevalent that it is literally called normal. I cannot find a way to specify to `Optuna` that my parameters have a `mean` and a `standard deviation`.

How do i tell `Optuna` the `mean` and `standard deviation` of my parameters?

The only distributions I can find in the documentation are: `suggest_uniform()`, `suggest_loguniform()` and `suggest_discrete_uniform()`.

Please tell me if I am somehow misunderstanding loguniform distrubution (It looks somewhat similar, but I can't specify a standard deviation?) or the pruning process.

As you might be able to tell from my text, I've spent a frustrating amount of time trying to figure this out and gotten exactly nowhere, any help will be highly appreciated!

Special thanks to dankal444 for this elegant solution (i will replace the mean and std with my own values):

```
from scipy.special import erfinv
space = {
    'B1': (erfinv(trial.suggest_float('B1', -1, 1))-mean)*std,
    'B2': ...
}
```

Comment: Optuna works like this: You inform what variable to change and the range of values of that variable, then you can ask what value to try, then you test that value on your objective function and you send the objective value to optuna then ask again what value to try ...

Comment: Yes but the values that are tried are taken from a distribution, you can ofcourse give an equally distributed set of numbers between two values, but what I needed is provided by dankal444 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cheat `optuna` by using uniform distribution and transforming it into normal distribution. To do that one of the method is [inversed error function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.erfinv.html) implemented in `scipy`.

Function takes uniform distribution from in range <-1, 1> and converts it to standard normal distribution

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import special


x = np.linspace(-1, 1)
plt.plot(x, special.erfinv(x))
plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$erf(x)$')

mean = 2
std = 3
random_uniform_data = np.random.uniform(-1 + 0.00001, 1-0.00001, 1000)
random_gaussianized_data = (special.erfinv(random_uniform_data) - mean) * std
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
axes[0].hist(random_uniform_data, 30)
axes[1].hist(random_gaussianized_data, 30)
axes[0].set_title('uniform distribution samples')
axes[1].set_title('erfinv(uniform distribution samples)')
plt.show()
```

This is how the function looks like:

[image: inverse error function]

And below example of transforming of uniform distribution into normal with custom mean and standard deviation (see code above)

[image: transforming uniform to normal distribution]

Comment: You absolute legend!
I'm thinking about it, but if I understand it correctly, I should let Optuna pick a value between -1 and 1 as the parameter to optimize and compute the actual parameter values in the objective function itself correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just be careful with -1 and 1 because they will result as infinities in `inverf` funtion

Comment: That is an excellent addition, thank you again! typically the kind of error that will crash a study at 3 a.m. wasting half the night in compute resources.